# Is it wrong to not implement all REST actions in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, scaffolding

Let's say I have a `SessionsController`, which controls user login and logout, but the only actions I really need are **new** (for displaying login form), **create** (for authentication and login) and **destroy** for logging out the user.

**Is there any problem if I just have these three actions in my controller, or do I have to implement them all to make it correctly RESTful?**

And second little question. Some people say that *scaffolding* is bad, and that one should write code by hand, but I find it pretty useful and time saving.

**Is it OK to use scaffolding, or is it evil that should be avoided and why?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is definitely okay to only create the RESTful actions which you want to support for that resource. You do not have to define all 7 actions. In fact, the majority of my controllers do not use all 7 actions.

> Is it OK to use scaffolding, or is it
>   evil that should be avoided and why?

The built-in Rails scaffolding is mainly designed to help get off the ground when beginning. I personally don't use it for everyday development for a few reasons.

- it generates a CSS and layout file when I want to use the existing application one
- it generates all controller actions (like I said I usually don't want all of them)
- it creates an XML format for every action which I almost never want
- it does not put the form in a partial when I need both "edit" and "new" actions
- I sometimes use a different testing library (such as Shoulda or RSpec)

However, I am a fan of scaffolding for speeding up development. This is why I created the [nifty_scaffold generator](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/tree/master) which I use almost all the time. It does not have the problems mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with implementing only those actions which you need.  In Rails 2.3 you can be even more explicit in your routes as well.

map.resources :foo, :only => [:create, :destroy, :new]

Answer (score 1):

Remember REST only really has 4 verbs GET, POST, <del>UPDATE</del> PUT and DELETE. 
The edit and new actions in Rails are workarounds of the GET verb to display the form for editing the resource. The index action is a GET on a different resource, its just bundled with the others because in an application development context it makes more sense to have it in that same file.

Comment: REST does not define any actions.  I'm presuming you are referring to the four main HTTP verbs GET, PUT, POST and DELETE.  HTTP does have other verbs though.